# drag and drop, prevent awkward highlighting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drag-and-drop

I'm building a drag and drop method, using query
-onmousedown
leading to -onmousemove (drag) then -onmouseup (unbinds onmousemove)

the problem is, browser defaults begin highlighting onmousemove, which flies all over the page and cancels the event, rendering it unusable. any idea how to prevent highlighting, for preventDefault seems not to be working. here is my code (yes its very sloppy, sorry!)

```
$(".middleRow").mousedown(function(){
 calculateSelection();

  $('body').append('<div class="messageDrag" style="display:block">'+numSelected+'<div        style="font-size: 18px">messages</div></div>');


 $(document).mouseup(function(){

        $('.messageDrag').fadeOut(500);

        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.messageDrag').remove();
        }, 500);


        $(document).unbind();


    })


$(document).mousemove(function(e){


    e.preventDefault();


    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    $(".messageDrag").css("left", x-49);
    $(".messageDrag").css("top", y-49);


});

 });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could disable highlighting using css

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

another way of doing this is to clear selection on drop event, as so:

```
function clearSelection() {
    var sel;
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty){
        document.selection.empty() ;
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if(sel && sel.removeAllRanges)
        sel.collapse();
    }
}
```

So you would call `clearSelection()` on drop event (after the drag is finished)

Comment: i don't want to completely remove highlighting, only during this dragging state. but i could throw this css in through query as such, does this have full browser support?

Comment: yes it should cover most modern browsers (hence all the vendor prefixes, even ms), you could do `$(element).css({// the css above});` when drag is initialized, and set them to `auto` once the drop is done.

Comment: hmm..this doesn't seem to prevent highlighting, just gets rid of it visually. the bigger problem was the act of highlighting (as the user begins the drag over text, highlight occurs, or if at the beginning he drags over it it cancels the drag and starts highlighting) and it is ruining the drag and drop.

Comment: Hmm ok, understood... let me find out other way

Comment: Edited my answer, please see if that fits :)

Comment: as of 2023, you can just use user-select: none, as all browsers support it.

Answer (score 2):

add css

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;/*for mobile*/
-webkit-user-select: none;/*for chrome*/
-khtml-user-select: none;/*for safari*/
-moz-user-select: none;/*for Mozilla*/
-ms-user-select: none;/*for mircosoft*/
-o-user-select: none;/*for opera*/
user-select: none;/*base css ,but not work in all browsers*/
```