# Disable select while doing mouse drag on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to disable the select while dragging an image. But it does not seems to work. I know similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627732/drag-and-drop-prevent-awkward-highlighting) has already been asked but none seems to work for me.

I also tried to enter this in css as suggested in many similar questions.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;/*for mobile*/
-webkit-user-select: none;/*for chrome*/
-khtml-user-select: none;/*for safari*/
-moz-user-select: none;/*for Mozilla*/
-ms-user-select: none;/*for mircosoft*/
-o-user-select: none;/*for opera*/
user-select: none;/*base css ,but not work in all browsers*/
```

[image]

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zdzjt2k1/2/)

Comment: use the following -webkit-user-select: none;

Answer (score 1):

Use user-drag css option

```
img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none; 
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure op wants to keep mouse drag events and this prevents the mouse drag events from firing.

Comment: In that case i'm not really sure if is it possible to accomplish what he want to do :(

Comment: Agreed.  Depending on browser support requirements, he could override the drag image with an empty image.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage` to a transparent canvas of 1px and mouse drag still works

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");

document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(c, 0, 0);
}, false);


document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zdzjt2k1/5/)